# Slim 3 - How to add multiple middleware classes on a route?

Tags: slim

I know how to add multiple middleware class in `$app`:

```
$app->add( new Middlewares\VerifyCsrfToken() );
$app->add( new Middlewares\RemoveTrailingSlash() );
```

But how on route?

```
$app->get('/', function($request, $response){
     return $response;
})->add( new Middlewares\VerifyCsrfToken() )
  ->add( new Middlewares\RemoveTrailingSlash() );
```

Comment: This is exactly correct.

Comment: Really? haha I'll give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: Example: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/tests/AppTest.php#L775-L793

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `add()` returns an instance of the `Route` object, so you can simply chain multiple `add()`s together.

This [unit test](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/tests/AppTest.php#L775-L793) shows how to do it:

```php
$app = new App();

$app->get('/', function ($req, $res) {
    return $res->write('Center');
})->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $res->write('In1');
    $res = $next($req, $res);
    $res->write('Out1');
    return $res;
})->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $res->write('In2');
    $res = $next($req, $res);
    $res->write('Out2');
    return $res;
});
```

Comment: Is the order from top to bottom?

Comment: Inside out, so the last one added is the first one executed.

Comment: The last one added will be the first one executed.
So lets say you have a session middleware that you will use in your other middlewares make sure you add it at last ;)